# How to sum specific rows of a matrix

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I need to sum the matrix elements of specific rows for each column. An example of the matrix is given below(input). So the matrix has 4 columns and 6 rows of numbers. I need to sum the numbers of specific rows for each column. I other words I need to sum the elements of row1 + row2 + row5 and row3 + row4 + row6 for each column.

Input :

```
   column1  column2 column3 column4    
     11.1     12       13     4          
     21.3     22       23     3                  
     31       32       33    45            
     41       42       43   536              
     23       32        6     5                   
      4        5        3     2
```

The output should looks like this.

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4    
    55.4    66      42      12
    76      79      79     583
```

I was trying to use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR==1{$1=$1; print; next} !(NR%2){split($0,a); next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i+=a[i]}1' file
```

but I cannot get the expected result.

Comment: Do you really need to do it in *bash* specifically, as per your title? Doing math in sed, as you have tagged, is tricky. Is awk acceptable?

Comment: @alloppp, please show your work so far and we can help correct any mistakes.

Comment: must use `awk` or another tool to sum up floats as `bash` doesn't handle floats

Comment: @glennjackman   I only can make the sum of the consecutive rows , see it :  awk 'NR==1{$1=$1; print; next} 
     !(NR%2){split($0,a); next}          
            {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i+=a[i]}1' file

Comment: I don't disagree, Don; I'm just on a miniature crusade to help people understand that while bash is powerful, the fact that it's your shell doesn't mean that it has to do everything (unless they, for some reason, can't or don't want to call an external binary).

Comment: alloppp use the [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/287200/edit) link to update your post

Comment: See and learn xD the elegant way to solve the problem using awk @JeffSchaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KISS implementation in `awk`:

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 {
        n=NF;print;next
    } 
    FNR == 2 || FNR == 3 || FNR == 6 {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i;
    } 
    FNR == 4 || FNR == 5 || FNR == 7 {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) b[i]+=$i
    } END {
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%8s", a[i]); print ""; 
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%8s", b[i]); print "";
    }
' file
```

Comment: Might as well use `i<=n` in the loops setting "a" and "b" arrays.

Comment: +1.  `FNR ~ /^(2|3|6)$/ { ... }` etc also works and is less tedious than typing lots of `|| FNR == `comparisons.